# How to get all of the headlines from a google news search using Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=tesla&oq=tesla&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j0l3.494j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=tesla&tbm=nws").userAgent("Mozilla").get();

    Elements links = doc.select("div[class=_cnc]");
    for (Element link : links) {
        Elements titles = link.select("h3.r_U6c");
        String title = titles.text();
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println("Headline: " + link.text());
        System.out.println("Link: " + link.attr("data-href"));  
    }
      }}
```

Here is the HTMl layout. I want to extract the titles for each of the links. I am just not sure on how to format the CSS selector portions of my code. I tried to look through some old threads but couldn't get anything to work. I am just looking for the text of the headlines not the actual links. The print link statements were just for some testing that I couldn't get running.

Thanks guys 
[Picture of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y373.png)

Answer (score 1):

The page you're trying to fetch is loaded with Javascript. Jsoup don't process Javascript scripts.

Instead use some tools like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) or [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j).